# How to toggle class from a child to another in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parent-child

```
<html>
<head><title>Don't Know</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child random">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to toggle class "random" from one child (p tag) to another child(p tag). How am I supposed to do that with less Javascript/Jquery code?

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle class random from one child to another"?

Comment: Do you want to cycle classes between elements on click??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this decision is from me.

```js
$('.child').on('click', function() {
  $('.child').removeClass('style_for_p');
  $(this).addClass('style_for_p');
});
```

```css
.child {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.style_for_p {
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <p class="child random">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```css
.random {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Don't Know</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child random">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
  <p class="child">Lorem Ipsum<p>
</div>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".child").forEach((child) => {
  child.onclick = () => {
     document.querySelector(".random").classList.remove("random");
     child.classList.add("random");
  };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Click on a `p` element to remove the `random` class from where it was before and add it to the new element.

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```js
 const childEl = document.querySelectorAll(".child");
 childEl.forEach((child) => {
    child.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.querySelector(".random").classList.remove("random");
        child.classList.add("random");
     });
 });
```